# is there some kind of symbolic links that support moving or renaming the target file?

Tags: symlink, hard-link

I liked this explanation of hard and soft/symbolic links: [Why are hard links to directories not allowed in UNIX/Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22406/42226)

Now the reason why I googled about soft and hard links is simply because I was organizing my folders and files and in one point I wanted one file to be referenced to from another directory. So I thought in shortcuts/symlinks, but would like to be able to rename the file or move it to another folder and still have the symlinks pointing to that file.

Is that possible?

Hard link isn't an option since I want the same functionality also for folders (and furthermore I want one reference -the first hard link- to be always the "most important").

Answer (score 1):

You may invert the logic here: just keep all relevant directories and regular files in a fixed, central directory, and move absolute symlinks around.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not exactly what I want. I'm looking for something simpler. It's not that hard to do I think, and it would be useful.