# How to create a hardlink to a directory in Solaris?

Tags: directory, solaris, hard-link

I started to study the Solaris in my university. Teacher told me to do a hardlink to a directory. And he said that I can not to use **mount** command. For example: `# mount -F lofs /dir1/dir2 /dir1/hardlink2`
I know that Unix doesn't allowed  hardlink to a directory. I was looking for other ways but I found nothing. And I don't know how I can do this hardlink.

Do you know way how create a hardlink to a directory in Solaris?

Comment: In most *nix operating systems, you have to be running as root (a.k.a. superuser) to create a hardlink to a directory. The operation is restricted because it can make a mess of a file system. See [Linux: How does hard-linking to a directory work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108843/80216)

Comment: @G-Man I'm running as root, but than I use ln command, it displays an error: .... is a directory. I read manual about ln. This command in Solaris has only 3 settings: -f-n (about messages), -s (symbolic link). So I can't use ln in this case.

Comment: Oh, yes, belt and suspenders. The _operating system_ doesn't allow a process to create a hardlink to a directory unless it's running as root -- but *also* the `ln` program doesn't allow a *user* (*any* user) to do it. (1) Check the man page for `ln` on your system. There may be an option (like `-d` or `-F`) to tell `ln` to override the restriction. (2) Check to see whether you have a `link` command. (3) If those don't work, try writing a one-line C program to call the `link` system call.

Comment: @G-Man `link` command works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like G-Man already gave you an answer, but another option, slightly sneaky if you have the automounter installed, you could use an automount.  Depending on the needs, this may be a little bit cleaner since linking a directory can cause confusion.