# Is there a difference between hardlinking with cp -l or ln?

Tags: cp, hard-link, ln

I am implementing a backup scheme using rsync and hardlinks. I know I can use link-dest with rsync to do the hardlinks, but I saw mention of using "cp -l" before "link-dest" was implemented in rsync. Another method of hardlinking I know of is "ln".

So my question is, out of curiosity: is there a difference in making hardlinks using "cp -l" as compared to using "ln"?

Comment: The links are indistinguishable.

Comment: You mean to say there's no difference? They could be used interchangeably?

Comment: I ran a little test myself, but couldn't see any difference between the two, at first sight.

Comment: `cp: illegal option -- l` are you sure that cp has an l option?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The results of both has to be the same, in that a hard link is created to the original file.

The difference is in the intended usage and therefore the options available to each command. For example, `cp` can use recursion whereas `ln` cannot:

```
cp -lr <src> <target>
```

will create hard links in `<target>` to all files in `<src>`. (it creates new directories; not links)  The result will be that the directory tree structure under `<target>` will look identical to the one under `<src>`.  It will differ from `cp -r <src> <target>` in that using the latter will copy each file and folder and give each a new `inode` whereas the former just uses hard links on files and therefore simply increases their `Links` count.

When used to copy a single file, as in your example, then the results will be the identical.

Comment: if I understand correctly, "cp -lr" will create hardlinks for all the files, but if there are missing directories in <target>, these will be created as new (i.e. no hardlinks to directories in <target>)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You cannot create hard links to directories.  Therefore in order to keep the file/directory structure, it becomes hard-links for files inside 'real' directories.

Comment: regarding the behavior for "cp -lr": hardlinks for files... new directories for directories. seems a little strange but I guess this "strange" behavior is a side effect of the constraints (can't have hardlinks of directories). ||| also FYI for reference here's some links to info on hardlinks not allowed for directoreis [ref1 from askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210741/why-are-hard-links-not-allowed-for-directories) and [ref2 from unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22394/why-are-hard-links-to-directories-not-allowed-in-unix-linux).

Answer (score 7):

*link* uses the least system calls, followed by *ln* and finally *cp*:

```
$ strace link f.txt g.txt | wc --lines
282

$ strace ln --symbolic f.txt g.txt | wc --lines
311

$ strace ln f.txt g.txt | wc --lines
334

$ strace cp --symbolic f.txt g.txt | wc --lines
394

$ strace cp --link f.txt g.txt | wc --lines
410
```