# What is the difference between 'rm' and 'unlink'?

Tags: symlink, rm

Assuming you know the target is a symbolic link and not a file, is there any difference between using `rm` and `unlink` to remove the link?

Comment: This is pretty well covered on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/38816/what-is-the-difference-between-unlink-and-rm

Comment: @slm♦ The answers correspond to that question, but this question is different, it says: "Assuming you know the target is a symbolic link and not a file".

Answer (score 104):

Anytime you have these types of questions it's best to conceive of a little test to see what's actually happening. For this you can use `strace`.

#### unlink

```
$ touch file1
$ strace -s 2000 -o unlink.log unlink file1
```

#### rm

```
$ touch file1
$ strace -s 2000 -o rm.log rm file1
```

When you take a look at the 2 resulting log files you can "see" what each call is actually doing.

#### Breakdown

With `unlink` it's invoking the `unlink()` system call:

```
....
mmap(NULL, 106070960, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d025cc000
close(3)                                = 0
unlink("file1")                         = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
....
```

With `rm` it's a slightly different path:

```
....
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "file1", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "file1", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "file1", W_OK)      = 0
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "file1", 0)          = 0
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
...
```

The system calls `unlink()` and `unlinkat()` are essentially the same except for the differences described in this man page: http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlinkat.

**excerpt**

> The unlinkat() system call operates in exactly the same way as either
>   unlink(2) or rmdir(2) (depending on whether or not flags includes the
>   AT_REMOVEDIR flag) except for the differences described in this manual
>   page.
>
> If the pathname given in pathname is relative, then it is interpreted
>   relative to the directory referred to by the file descriptor dirfd
>   (rather than relative to the current working directory of the calling
>   process, as is done by unlink(2) and rmdir(2) for a relative
>   pathname).
>
> If the pathname given in pathname is relative and dirfd is the special
>   value AT_FDCWD, then pathname is interpreted relative to the current
>   working directory of the calling process (like unlink(2) and
>   rmdir(2)).
>
> If the pathname given in pathname is absolute, then dirfd is ignored.

Comment: Since it's giving `AT_FDCWD`, there's effectively no difference between `unlink` and `unlinkat`.

Comment: It makes me happy to read this answer because I just "learned to fish" in a powerful, flexible way when often I get a fish or sometimes I "learn to fish" in a basic way on SO :-)

Answer (score 72):

POSIX specifies that the `unlink` utility calls the C library `unlink` function and nothing else. It takes no option. If you pass a valid path name to something which isn't a directory, and if you have write permissions to the directory where that object lives, then `unlink` will remove it.

`rm` is a traditional Unix command which has a bit of other functionality, and isn't quite a superset of `unlink` (see below).

Firstly, `rm` performs safety checks. If you try to `rm` an object to which you don't have write permissions (which are irrelevant to your ability to remove it: the containing directory's permissions are!) `rm` nevertheless refuses unless `-f` is specified.   `rm` normally complains if the file doesn't exist, as does `unlink`; however with `-f`, `rm` does not complain. This is often exploited in Makefiles (`clean: @rm -f $(OBJS) ...`) so `make clean` doesn't fail when there is nothing to remove.

Secondly, `rm` has the `-i` option for interactively confirming the delete.

Thirdly, `rm` has `-r` for recursively removing a directory, which is something that `unlink` isn't required to do, since the C library function doesn't do that.

**The `unlink` utility isn't exactly a stripped-down `rm`.** It performs a subset of what `rm` does, but it has semantics which is a combination of `rm` **with** `-f` and rm **without** `-f`.

**Suppose you want to just remove a regular file regardless of what its own permissions are. Furthermore, suppose you want the command to fail if the file doesn't exist, or any other reason.**  Neither `rm file` nor `rm -f file` meets the requirements. `rm file` will refuse if the file isn't writable.  But `rm -f file` will neglect to complain if the file is missing. `unlink file` does the job.

`unlink` was probably introduced because `rm` is too clever: sometimes you just want the pure Unix `unlink` semantics: *"please make this directory entry go away if directory permissions allow"*.

Comment: This is the clearest answer here.  It actually gives the *use case* for `unlink` rather than just describing differences.

Comment: Agreed. The **unlink(1)** tool is just a simple wrapper of **unlink(2)**, without additional features.

Answer (score 26):

With a single file, [rm](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html) and [unlink](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/unlink.html) do the same task, remove the file. As POSIX defined, `rm` and `unlink` both call to [unlink()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html) system call.

In GNU `rm`, it calls to [unlinkat()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html) system call, which is equivalent to the `unlink()` or [rmdir()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rmdir.html) function except in the case where path specifies a relative path.

**Note**

On some systems, `unlink` can also remove directory. At least in GNU system, `unlink` can never delete the name of a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Also with rm you can use glob to delete multiple files. With unlink you can delete one file at a time.

```
touch f{1..10}
rm f*           # works 

touch f{1..10}
unlink f*       # doesn't work (expands to unlink f1 f2 ... f10)
unlink f1       # works
```