# How to remove a file without using rm?

Tags: linux, rm

The third party scheduling application our enterprise uses doesn't execute  `rm` commands as expected. By this, I mean I expect the `rm -f $filetoremove` to complete and then continue to the next line of code in the script.

But I need to get it to execute preferrably `rm -f`.

Is there another method to remove a file without using `rm`?
I tried `> delete_foobar.file` but it just empties it without removing.

**Additional information**:
 My work environment is a large enterpise. I write the `.sh` script which I test outside the scheduling application.  Outside the scheduling software, the `rm -f $filetoremove` command works with a return code of `0`. However, the scheduling software does not register the `0` return code and immediately exits without running the remainder of the `.sh` script. This is problematic and the vendor has acknowledged this defect.

I'm not privy to the details of the automation software nor the exact return codes it receives. All I know, is that my scripts don't run completely, when run via the automation software, if it contains `rm`.  This is why I'm looking for alternatives to `rm`.

Yes, it is important that I remove the file once I've completed processing it.

Comment: What happens when you `rm`?

Comment: Please let us know what "as expected" means. We don't know if you're on a system _without_ `rm` or if simple has a malformed `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Is removing the content of the file enough? (the file itself will be kept)

Comment: rm, after executing,  returns a non zero return code to the application, or the application mis-reads the return code of 0 as something else In either case, the application then proceeds to exit without excuting the remainder of the script. The vendor has acknowledged this as a defect.

Comment: @zundarz: You can get a more useful answer if you provide more info, e.g. the command-line arguments the application runs `rm` with, the error message of `rm`, the value of `$PATH` when the application runs `rm`. Most probably `rm` is working just fine on your system (and there is no better alternative), but the application invokes it incorrectly.

Comment: If the script is unable to correctly execute `rm` and detect its exit status, then that will likely also be an issue for any of the other ways that people come up with to delete files in the answers to this question.

Comment: Create a shell script called `die_file_die_bu_wa_ha_ha_ha_ha.sh` or whatever you like containing `#!bash \n rm -f $1 \n exit 0\n`, make sure it's on your path, and use this instead of `rm`. (Obviously, replace the `\n`'s with real newlines in your file).

Comment: This continues to sound like a defect in the scheduling software, or a misunderstanding of how it works. If `rm` works in your script, then I think you'll need help from the scheduler vendor.

Comment: Correct, this defect appears applicable only to rm when run in the scheduling software. Until they fix this, I'm left with other alternatives to get my scripts working.

Comment: Another trick is to erase but do not delete the fil. eg:

    echo > $filetoremove

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`unlink`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/unlink.html) command is also part of POSIX:

```
unlink <file>
```

Comment: Also see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151951/135943

Answer (score 8):

Are you able to run `shred`?  If so, then:

```
shred -u <file to remove>
```

Answer (score 7):

> Is there another method to remove a file without using `rm`?

```
busybox rm -f path/to/file
```

This is assuming your scheduling application allows you to run `busybox` unrestricted. Since you haven't specified which application it is, we don't really know what the restrictions are, but the above should work if the application has a simple molly guard preventing execution of just `rm`.

Answer (score 6):

With a GNU `find`, `find /your/file -delete` could work.

Answer (score 1):

Move the file to /tmp:

`mv filename /tmp`

and it will be deleted at the next reboot.

Comment: Next reboot may be years away. Last time I rebooted my Linux laptop was a couple of month ago. Last time I rebooted my Linux server was... never?

Comment: @AleksG Did you just tell us you didn't do security updates for a very long time?

Comment: @MaxRied No.  I do them all the time - there's never been a need to restart the machine though.  They are all applied inline with corresponding modules unloaded/reloaded and services restarted.  But the actual machine does not need restarting.

Comment: @MaxRied It's not windows, remember?

Comment: @AleksG *the actual machine does not need restarting.*  What about the parts of the kernel that aren't modules?  So yes it does need reboots, unless you want to remain on your old base kernel version and not fix any security issues in that part of the kernel.  So you're probably still vulnerable to issues such as CVE-2016-9754 and likely a host of other security issues.

Comment: *Move the file to /tmp ..and it will be deleted at the next reboot.*?  That's not likely to work - most Linux distributions are configured such that `/tmp` contents are preserved across reboots.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Base kernel security vulns are the rarest of the breed.  Yes, they do occur, but those are analysed on a case by case basis.  The CVE-2016-9754 you refer to isn't a big deal for my laptop, as I am the only user, have full root access anyway and don't really care about local privilege escalation vulns. Ditto with my server, where all local users already have full sudo access; the server is hardened as much as possible and exposed serices are run behind chroot with absolutely minimal privileges.