# Restrict a Specifc Command

Tags: linux, sudo, rm

I want to restrict "rm" command to user who have a sudo access.

example:
bob ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:ALL

I have given SSH Access to"bob".

i want to restrict "bob" to run "rm" command. Even though if switched to root.  Any help!

Comment: `se-linux` I think that's almost the only way to do this.

Comment: Sry  I dint get u, Can you please elaborate...!

Comment: Not possible. Nothing stops bob from making a copy of `rm` or writing their own `rm` and running it.

Comment: sounds like an XY-Problem see http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't achieve such a goal.
You have several way to remove file from a linux system.

```
shred /path/to/file
busybox rm /path/to/file
find /path/to/file -delete
mv filename /tmp #file deleted at the reboot
```

The point here is that there's many way to remove file your best shot is to manage proper rwx authorization and eventually avoid file being remove with `selinux`.

Example from question [How to remove file without rm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342598/53092)

Comment: The last one works only if `/tmp` is stored in `RAM`.

Comment: if /tmp is erased at reboot which is the case on most linux today even if not tmpfs

Comment: Or rather at next startup.  Also, how do you know that it would happen on `most linux` and only some?

Comment: i want the bob to switch into root but he cannot  execute "rm" command

Comment: @hemasaimaddipati it's not possible. Forget about that. Except maybe with selinux but it wouldn't be perfect as there is so many other way to do this. Regarding /tmp it's just an example to illustrate the different possible way. I don't care if it actually is the case on one linux or another, it will be the case on most recent linux.