# ln -sfn vs rm vs unlink

Tags: symlink

I would like to remove a symlink and link it to something different, and I think there are 3 ways to do this:

```
ln -sfn source dest
```

```
rm dest
ln -s source dest
```

```
unlink dest
ln -s source dest
```

Are all 3 of these equivalent? Should one be preferred over another?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [What is the difference between 'rm' and 'unlink'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151951)

Comment: equivalent – with respect to what? On a level of results? or on a level of syscalls being executed? Or do you care about safety against race conditions?

Comment: the two latter ones leave a moment in time when the symlink doesn't exist, while in the first case, the `ln` implementation at least may attempt an atomic replace (by renaming a new symlink on top of the old, since the `symlink()` syscall itself will fail if the target already exists). No surprise, the GNU coreutils implementation seems to do exactly that, while the Busybox one just does the simple `unlink()`+`symlink()` combination

Comment: @MarcusMüller In this case, just the results

Comment: Related: [How does one atomically change a symlink to a directory in busybox?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/5093)

Answer (score 4):

They are not equivalent.

In:

```
ln -sfn source dest
```

The `-n` option to not dereference the destination is a non-standard extension (I believe from GNU `ln`, added there in version 3.10 in 1994). Some other `ln`s have `-h` for the same feature (such as NetBSD since 1997), and on some others, like Solaris/Illumos `-n` is for something else (predates GNU `ln`'s `-n`).

Assuming the GNU behaviour of `-n`, if `dest` exists as a directory, that creates a `dest/source` file replacing a file by that same name if any as long as it's not itself  a directory.

Otherwise, if creates a `dest` symlink to `source` replacing the existing file if any.

`ln` like `cp` or `mv` have that annoying ambiguous interface where they can do either move/copy/link *to* the destination or *into* the destination but that's decided based on the type of the last argument (or number of arguments) as opposed to what the user wants.

In:

```
rm dest
ln -s source dest
```

`rm` will attempt to remove a `dest`, possibly prompting the user under some conditions, and regardless of whether `rm` succeeded or not will run `ln -s source dest` which will create either `dest/source` (if `dest` is a directory which `rm` could not have removed or a symlink to a directory which `rm` may have been unable to remove for instance because you don't have write access to the current directory), or `dest` as a symlink to source (failing if a non-directory file exits by that name).

With:

```
unlink dest
ln -s source dest
```

Same except for the prompting part and for the fact that on some systems and under some conditions, `unlink` may be able to unlink a directory. `unlink` is also flagged under the XSI option in the POSIX specification and will not be as widely available as `rm`.

So if the intention is to try to create a `dest` symlink to `source`, you rather want:

- GNU specific:

  ```
  ln -sfT source dest
  ```

  (where `-T` disables the *into* mode, treating `dest` as the intended file to create regardless of whether it's a directory or not).
- Portable:

  ```
  rm -f dest && ln -sf source dest
  ```

  `rm` with `-f` does not prompt the user and does not fail if the file wasn't there in the first place. When it succeeds, you know the file is no longer there (or at least wasn't at the time `rm` checked after it succeeded to remove it). Beware however that `ln` could still create a `source/dest` symlink if someone else (re)created a `dest` directory or symlink to directory in-between those `rm` and `ln`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ln -sfn source dest
```

At least the documentation of GNU coreutils `ln` is misleading. It says:

> `-f, --force`
>                      remove existing destination files

In reality, what GNU `ln -f` does is making a new symlink under a temporary name, and calling `renameat`, which simply replaces the target symlink atomically. It does **not** first remove the existing symlink.

In general, that's desirable, so not sure why `man ln` lies.

> In this case, just the results

Then things don't differ.