# Hard links vs. Soft links: When would you want to use one over the other?

Tags: symlink, hard-link

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between symbolic and hard links?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9575/what-is-the-difference-between-symbolic-and-hard-links)

Today, my teacher talked about the differences between 'hard links' and 'soft links', but she never really explained why we need to use them, which basically made me curious about why there needs to be a hard link vs. soft link choice when it seems like they serve the same functionality. Aren't they both used as indirect links to a target file? I have never used the unix command line very much, so I guess I've never really been exposed to the commands in action

Thanks :)