# Purpose of hard link and soft link

Tags: symlink, hard-link

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between symbolic and hard links?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9575/what-is-the-difference-between-symbolic-and-hard-links)

I've read quite a few articles regarding hard links and soft links, but I still dont understand the purpose of these two.

What happens if you hard link a file,
and what happens if you soft link a file?

I want to know theif functions i.e. what happens if the soft link is deleted, or the physical file is deleted?

does the soft link or hard link keeps the original file updated and which of the two writes to the original file and which doesnt if so why whats the point of soft and hard links