# rsync --link-dest not working as expected with symlinks

Tags: rsync, symlink, hard-link

I'm using `rsync` to backup some of my files:

`rsync -aEN --delete --link-dest="$CURR/" "$SOURCE/" "$NEW/"`

The `--link-dest` option works fine with most files, but not with symlinks.
When I was writing a clean-up script for old backups, I noticed that unchanged symlinks are not hard-linked, but rather copied.

Now I'm wondering:
Is there a way to make `rsync` hard-link unchanged symlinks as well?
And if not: Is it intentional or a bug in rsync?

I'm using rsync version 3.1.1 on Mac OS 10.11.

**Edit:**

It seems to be a problem in Mac OS X. For some reason HFS+ seems not to support hard-links to symlinks.

Comment: The `--copy-links` option is probably what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure you can create a hard link to a symbolic link...

Comment: Sure, you cannot.  But the `--copy-links` option copies the files to which the links point (which is as close as OP will get to what was intended).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filesystem on macOS (HFS+) does not support hard links to symbolic links:

```
$ touch file
$ ls -l file
-rw-r--r-- 1 kk staff 0 Jun 17 18:35 file

$ ln -s file slink
$ ls -l file slink
-rw-r--r-- 1 kk staff 0 Jun 17 18:35 file
lrwxr-xr-x 1 kk staff 4 Jun 17 18:36 slink -> file
```

The following would ordinarily create a hard link to a symbolic link, and is even documented in the `ln` manual on macOS to do so (EDIT: no it isn't, unless you have GNU coreutils installed and read the wrong manual, doh!):

```
$ ln -P slink hlink
$ ls -l file slink hlink
-rw-r--r-- 1 kk staff 0 Jun 17 18:35 file
lrwxr-xr-x 1 kk staff 4 Jun 17 18:38 hlink -> file
lrwxr-xr-x 1 kk staff 4 Jun 17 18:36 slink -> file
```

You can see by the ref count (1) that no new name was created for `slink` (would have been 2 for both `slink` and `hlink` if it had worked). Also, `stat` tells us that `hlink` is a symbolic link with 1 inode link (not 2):

```
$ stat hlink
  File: 'hlink' -> 'file'
  Size: 4               Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 1000004h/16777220d      Inode: 83828644    Links: 1
Access: (0755/lrwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  501/      kk)   Gid: (   20/   staff)
Access: 2016-06-17 18:38:18.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2016-06-17 18:38:18.000000000 +0200
Change: 2016-06-17 18:38:18.000000000 +0200
 Birth: 2016-06-17 18:38:18.000000000 +0200
```

EDIT: Since I was caught using GNU coreutils, here's the tests again with `/bin/ln` on macOS:

```
$ touch file
$ /bin/ln -s file slink
$ /bin/ln slink hlink   # there is no option corresponding to GNU's -P
$ ls -l file slink hlink
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  staff  0 Jun 17 18:59 file
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  staff  0 Jun 17 18:59 hlink
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kk  staff  4 Jun 17 18:59 slink -> file
```

The hard link is pointing to `file` rather than to `slink`.

On e.g. Linux and OpenBSD (the other OSes I use), it is possible to do this, which results in

```
$ ls -l file slink hlink
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kk kk 0 Jun 17 18:35 file
lrwxrwxrwx 2 kk kk 4 Jun 17 18:43 hlink -> file
lrwxrwxrwx 2 kk kk 4 Jun 17 18:43 slink -> file
```

(notice "2")

Comment: That answers my question, thank you. Puzzles me why it isn't implementet, considering even hard-linking directories is implemented in HFS+.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that fact was a bit humorous too.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make hardlinks to symbolic links (this is not a "limitation" of OS X). A hardlink is a reference to an inode, and a symbolic link is not an inode but only an entry in the directory with some additional information.

You may be thinking of Windows, which has analogous features, which behave differently.

`rsync` *does* have a `--copy-links` option which tells it to copy the file to which a symbolic link points to the destination.  That would be useful if you are trying to construct a complete replica of your source directory (but not very useful if your goal is to reduce disk usage).

- [What is the difference between symbolic and hard links?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9575/what-is-the-difference-between-symbolic-and-hard-links)
- [Symlinks vs Hardlinks and how to create them](http://bencane.com/2013/10/10/symlinks-vs-hardlinks-and-how-to-create-them/)
- [Hard Links and Junctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Windows)
- [**`rsync`** - faster, flexible replacement for rcp](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html)
- [link, ln -- make links](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ln.1.html)

Comment: I believe you're wrong. See my answer.

Comment: Your example isn't in the manual page which I am reading.  By the way, making comments like that is unfriendly.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know how to put it in another way; I'm able to make hard links to symbolic links on Linux and on other Unices, but not on OS X HFS+. The manual says "-P, --physical make hard links directly to symbolic links", but that's not what's happening.

Comment: My bad. It turns out I had the GNU coreutils installed. That's where that manual comes from. Still, I can create a hard link to a symbolic link on other OSes...

Comment: It's a recent feature in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html), which doesn't appear to be documented for OSX.  `rsync` isn't in POSIX, doesn't have to support new features.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to create hard-links to symlinks. Anyway I just tested it on Linux and it worked fine. As for Windows, I don't know what features it offers. I've avoided it for the last 14 or so years.

Comment: It depends.  The rsync program takes it into account (see [log entry](https://git.samba.org/rsync.git/?p=rsync.git;a=commit;h=ba43e88527980718f99b680c3a3e3e2a3a97b6f3)).