# Can rsync be used to make only hard links, not copies?

Tags: osx, rsync, backup, hard-link

I'm working on a system to automatically back up my computer using `rsync` and the Google Drive app (I have a Macintosh computer). (This app creates a directory whose contents are saved to the Google Drive cloud.) The idea of the backup system is to (automatically) copy files to the Google Drive directory (using `rsync`, preferably) then upload the directory to the cloud.

This system has a major drawback, however: memory waste. Every file that I backup has to be copied to a second location in my computer, doubling the space the file uses. It would be *much* more memory efficient to make hard links instead of copies. I would like to duplicate my directory tree using hard links, then update the duplicate when the original changes.

Can I use `rsync` to make hard links instead of copies? I think this might be possible with the `link--dest=` option, but I can't figure it out.

**Edit**: A few clarifications, in response to feedback.

1. This question has been listed as a duplicate of  [rsync --link-dest not working as expected with symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/290420/177447). I don't understand why the questions are the same. I gather that the similarity has to do with using the `--link-dest=` option to create hardlinks. But this is what I don't understand how to do! So I'm not satisfied with the duplicate question. It seems like using `--link-dest=` to make hardlinks only works if you already have a backup to compare it to.
2. I'm not computer proficient compared to the users of this site. If the answer to my question is something like "this is easy, just read the man page for `rsync` more carefully" or something like that, I'll do it.
3. I'm perfectly happy using some other bash utility to achieve the functionality I'm looking for! I just happen to like `rsync`, but I'm open to other options. JdeBP has suggested using `pax`, for example.

Comment: You've excessively limited yourself by restricting your toolset to `rsync` in the question.  [`pax`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pax.1.html) in _copy mode_ is a tool that you could be using, for example.

Comment: A minor quibble. It wouldn't be more _memory_ efficient to use hard links. But it would be more _disk storage_ efficient.

Comment: @JdeBP I should have said this in the post, but I'm very open to using other tools besides rsync! I just have no idea what I'm doing. I'll look into pax.

Comment: @roaima I was unaware of the distinction. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

The usual method is (writing from memory):

```
NEWBACKUP=`date +%s` # or some other format
cp -al "$OLDBACKUP" "$NEWBACKUP"
rsync -aH --delete "$SOURCE" "$NEWBACKUP"
```

Check out [Easy Automated Snapshot-Style Backups with Linux and Rsync](http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/)

There is also a `--link-dest` option to rsync that I've never investigated properly.

Comment: In the third line, is it still possible that rsync will make duplicate copies? It seems like this will delete files that no longer exist but then use standard rsync behavior to copy modified files instead of hardlinking them.

Comment: The script I gave is for creating a self-contained backup on another disk (presumably removable or remote); sorry if that was not what you wanted.