# How to affect only files who only have paths within a directory?

Tags: files, permissions, directory, chmod

If i understand it correctly, in linux, a file can have an arbitrary number of paths. Suppose some user wants to change permission of their `/home/<user>` files so that all their files can't be read by other users. Intuitively it would make sense to run `chmod o-r -R ~`. However, by my initial remark this seems like a potentially bad idea: there could be files in a (sub)directory of said user's home that are also in outside of it, and we wouldn't want to change the permissions of those. What should then be done instead?

Comment: Change the permission on the directory - `/home/<user>/` - no further access possible

Comment: Normally, the directories in /home only have permissions set for the owner. This shouldn't be necessary unless something was done to change them.

Comment: @AnswerMyQuestion, do you have some particular use-case as to why you'd have files with names inside someone's $HOME and outside it? And, just to make clear, I suppose you mean files hard linked in and out of the home directory, and not just symlinks?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly true that files in a user's `home` directory could be symlinks that point to files outside his home directory. And `chmod` will change the permissions of the target of a symlink, as the permissions of the symlink itself are generally not used. But checking the man page for `chmod` we see "chmod ignores symbolic links encountered during recursive directory traversals." So your stated command `chmod o-r -R ~` will not affect anything that is not actually directly in your home directory.

A good place for more information on this is the man pages for `chmod`, `chown`, and `ls`.

Comment: think hard links

Comment: Fair point. But there's not a lot about hardlinks published out there. I think in that case, though, what would control would be who was the owner of the file; if you own a file, can I set permissions on it, if I've got a hardlink in my home directory?

Comment: what do you mean "not a lot about hard links published"? See e.g.  [What is the difference between symbolic and hard links?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9575/170373) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-link?tab=Votes

Comment: only the file owner can set the permissions on it. But others may be able to read it, if it's accessible to them through some path.

Comment: Man pages seem to spend a lot more time on how symlinks are handled than hardlinks. But no matter... seems to me that the OP's question is now answered. If it's a symlink, chmod will not change it; if it's a hardlink, it will only get changed if he owns the file. And yeah, I'll shut up now.